# understanding assembly language lea instruction

Tags: assembly

I don't understand why line 8 is performed, can anyone explain it please? 
On line 10 strcpy is called, but 0x80482c4 doesn't contain any reference to 'hello world' (checked with gdb). My thinking is that esp is pointing to the starting memory address of 'hello world' and esp is being executed when strcpy is called? My guess at line 9 is that it is setting up enough space for the 'hello world' char array but in the code it was initialized to 20.

```
1.  push     ebp
2.  mov      ebp,esp
3.  sub      esp,0x38 // why does this happen?
4.  and      esp, 0xfffffff0
5.  mov      eax,0x0
6.  sub      esp,eax
7.  mov      DWORD PTR [esp+4],0x80484c4 //contains 'h'
8.  lea      eax,[ebp-40] // what is going on here? why ebp-40 bytes?
9.  mov      DWORD PTR [esp], eax 
10. call     0x80482c4 <strcppy@plt>
11. lea      eax,[ebp-40]
12. mov      DWORD PTR [esp],eax
13. call     0x80482d4 <printf@plt>
14. leave
15. ret
```

C equivalent:
    #include 
    #include

```
int main() {
char str_a[20];

strcpy(str_a, "Hello, world!\n");
printf(str_a);
}
```

Comment: One of the resons could be that printf deals better with even aligned data, so compiler aligns it even instead of letting it, where it is ( perhaps even, perhaps odd ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 0x80482c4 doesn't contain any reference to 'hello world' (checked with
>   gdb)

You must have checked wrong. You probably just printed the first letter, which is `h` (or `H`). It's 99% sure that's your `hello world` string.

Line 3 is setting up the space for your local variables, and the compiler has chosen to place your `str_a` at `ebp-40`. The `lea` is just loading that address.

It's generally hard to tell why the compiler chooses a specific stack layout, as long as there is space for everything, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Makes more sense, thanks for answering. On line 7, 0x80484c4 is the first byte containing the letter h so why is this not called into strcpcy instead of 0x80482c4?

Comment: `0x80482c4` is the address of `strcpy` itself.

Comment: Last one: why do we need line 7 and 8? cant we just move the address of ebp-40 into esp? I don't understand why we need to move the memory address of 'h' into esp + 4 and also move mem address of str_a into esp.

Comment: @bigl because in your OS calling convention parameters are passed on the stack. Those instructions are essentially equivalents to two `push`. Drawing a sketch of the stack (with ESP and EBP pointer) will help you get the whole picture :) ... and remember stack grows down, everything below ESP does not exist